# What data structures allow for efficient lookup in nested intervals?

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, intervals

I’m looking for a data structure that would help me find the smallest interval (the (*low*, *high*) pair) that encloses a given point. Intervals may nest properly. For example:

*Looking for point 3 in (2,7), (2,3), (4,5), (8,12), (9,10) should yield (2,3).*

During the construction of the data structure, intervals are added in no particular order and, specifically, not according to their nesting. Is there a good way to map this problem to a search tree data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) should do the job. In nodes of a segment tree you keep the length of the shortest interval that covers this node, as well as the reference to the interval itself. When processing a query for a given point, you simply return the interval referenced by the node of that point.